# How to implement a google credential in android for youtube api v3

Tags: android, google-oauth, credentials, youtube-data-api

In this code i have to pass the credential of OAuth.

```
try {
        // Authorize the request.
        Credential credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "myuploads");

        // This object is used to make YouTube Data API requests.
        youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(
                "youtube-cmdline-myuploads-sample").build();
```

does anyone knows how to get the google credential in android application.